# How to split cells with two numbers and apply conditional formatting only to the second number?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I have two numbers in P column, separated by a comma in Google Sheets spreadsheet. I want to make a conditional rule that only applies to the second number, where if the number is greater than -5, it is red. How do I do this?

Column Example:

[image]

`=SPLIT(P1, ",")[1] > 5` is an invalid formula

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question [useless for others](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) or images, which are [hard to copy](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

`choosecols` maybe used to get a specific index(column) in an array:

```js
=choosecols(split(P1,","),2) > -5
```

Comment: This worked well, but I needed to edit the range =choosecols(split(P1:P25, ","),2) > -5. Is there a more efficient way to apply the formula to the entire P column without having to put in the range though?

Comment: Within `Conditional format rules` setting → you have the ***Apply to range*** thing where you would input the P:P or a different range of choice

Answer (score 0):

You can also only apply SPLIT(), and then use Conditional formatting in the column R